# Python XML Parsing: Returning a specific Attribute Tag Value

Tags: python, xml, parsing, attributes, iterator

So assuming this is a snippet for an XML output, and I'm only interested in the name="app" data (i.e. search) highlighted below:

```
      <s:key name="modifiable">1</s:key>
      <s:key name="sharing">global</s:key>
      **<s:key name="app">search</s:key>**
      <s:key name="can_write">1</s:key>
      <s:key name="ttl">600</s:key>
```

Is it possible to return that specific value using `xml.dom.minidom` method without having to iterate?

I know how to save the above to a list using:

```
keysList = xmlfile.getElementByTagName('s:key')
```

and then iterate through keysList and using an "if" match statement:

```
iter.attributes['name'].value == "app"
```

However, I was wondering if there is a function that exists which will just give me the info I want...something like

```
keysList.getAttribute(name="app").value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `xml.dom.minidom` does not have any such function that can get you the required data - `search` - directly. And it does not have support for xpath either.

You should try using xml parsing libraries that support xpath , like [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) .

A simple example of what you want using [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) -

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> s="""<root>      <key name="modifiable">1</key>
...       <key name="sharing">global</key>
...       <key name="app">search</key>
...       <key name="can_write">1</key>
...       <key name="ttl">600</key></root>"""
>>> root = ET.fromstring(s)
>>> root.find('.//key[@name="app"]').text
'search'
```

---

Or [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) -

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree

In [2]: s="""<root>      <key name="modifiable">1</key>
   ...:       <key name="sharing">global</key>
   ...:       <key name="app">search</key>
   ...:       <key name="can_write">1</key>
   ...:       <key name="ttl">600</key></root>"""

In [6]: root = etree.fromstring(s)

In [7]: elements = root.xpath('.//key[@name="app"]')

In [8]: elements[0].text
Out[8]: 'search'
```

---

For `xml.dom.minidom` , you will have to do it by iterating over the result of `getElementByTagName('s:key')` like you are supposedly doing right now.

Comment: Hello, Can you confirm the above works with Name Spaces? i.e. elements = root.xpath('.//s.key[@name="app"]') and not just key

Comment: If you are using `lxml` , then you will need to pass the namespaces as argument. Example - `root.xpath('.//s:key[@name="app"]',namespaces={'s':'<the namesapce>'})` . More about it here - http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes